# NHibernate - filtering out results based on child-property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I have this code fetching all enabled Groups with their children. The problem I have is that the children can also be disabled but I can't get fluent nhibernate to only fetch groups where **all** childrens are enabled. I assume this is possible but how?

```
public class Group {
    public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ChildType> Children { get; protected set; }
}

public class ChildType {
    public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public IList<Group> Search(string searchString) {
    IQueryOver<Group> query = Session.QueryOver<Group>()
        .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Description).IsInsensitiveLike(searchString, MatchMode.Start)
        .Where(x => !x.IsDisabled)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Description).Asc
        .Fetch(group => group.Children).Eager;

    return query
        .Cacheable()
        .List();
}
```

**Edit:** There is a N:M-relation between children and groups.

The following is the solution I used:

```
public class Group {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ChildType> Children { get; protected set; }
}

public class ChildType {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Group> Groups { get; protected set; }
}

public IList<Group> Search(string searchString) {
    ChildType child = null;
    Group group = null;
    Group joinedGroup = null;

    var notDisabled = Session.QueryOver.Of<ExaminationType>()
        .Where(x => x.IsDisabled)
        .JoinAlias(x => x.Groups, () => joinedGroup )
            .Where(x => joinedGroup == group)
        .Select(x => x.Id);

    IQueryOver<Group> query = Session.QueryOver<Group>()
        .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Description).IsInsensitiveLike(searchString, MatchMode.Start)
        .JoinAlias(x => x.ExaminationTypes, () => child)
        .WithSubquery.WhereNotExists(notDisabled)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Description).Asc;

    return query
        .Cacheable()
        .List();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a subquery in order to achieve what you want. In order to do this though you're going to need to add a Group reference to the ChildType entity.

```
Group group = null;
var childCrit = QueryOver.Of<ChildType>()
        .Where(c => c.Group == group).And(c => c.IsDisabled)
        .Select(c => c.Id);
var query = Session.QueryOver(() => group)
        .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Description).IsInsensitiveLike(searchString, MatchMode.Start)
        .Where(x => !x.IsDisabled)
        .WithSubquery.WhereNotExists(childCrit)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Description).Asc
        .Fetch(group => group.Children).Eager;
```

This will get all groups that aren't disabled and have no disabled children.

Comment: There is an N:M-relation between groups and children making the subquery a bit annoying but if I solve that I guess this is the solution I'll use.

Thank you!

Comment: For the subquery you just need to use a `Select` to do a projection.

Answer (score 1):

```
public IList<Group> Search(string searchString) {

    Children children = null;

    IQueryOver<Group> query = Session.QueryOver<Group>()
        .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Description).IsInsensitiveLike(searchString, MatchMode.Start)
        .Where(x => !x.IsDisabled)
        .JoinAlias(x => x.Children, () => children)
            .Where(x => !x.IsDisabled)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Description).Asc;

    return query
        .Cacheable()
        .List();
}
```

That should do what you want to do.

Joining an alias will also fetch it for you.

http://www.philliphaydon.com/2011/04/nhibernate-querying-relationships-are-depth/

Comment: After changing
    .Where(x => !x.IsDisabled)
to
    .Where(x => !children.IsDisabled)
I got it to work somewhat but I get the groups if **any** of the childrens is enabled, not if **all** of them are.

Comment: @Fredrik - OH, sorry I mis-read that. I think you would have to do an exists, so query for all children that are enabled with no disabled ones, returning the Group, then querying the group WithSubquery.Exists on the previous query. http://www.philliphaydon.com/2011/01/revisiting-exists-in-nhibernate-3-0-and-queryover/ - I really need to sleep cos i got work tomorrow, I'll have a think about how the query would look and reply then.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I used the solution Vadim suggested.

Comment: @Fredrik - Yup awesome, he did exactly what I was thinking last night except with not-exists, which makes sense.