# Flitering an object child collection by a property using Fluent nHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

Please excuse my ignorance, I am new to nHibernate and am having a conceptual problem trying to filtering an child collection with an nHibernate query

My object model contains two entities User and Task set up like this

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Tasks = new List<Task>();
    }

    public User(int id): this()
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }

    public virtual IList<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public Task() { }

    public Task(int id, bool active): this()
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Active = active;
    }

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

My nHibernate mappings for these are as follows

```
public class UserMap: ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Table("user");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        HasMany(x => x.Tasks);
    }
}

public class TaskMap : ClassMap<Task>
{
    public TaskMap()
    {
        Table("task");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Active);
    }
}
```

My database has two tables 'task' and 'user' which I have filled thusly

```
SELECT * FROM task;
+----+--------+---------+
| Id | Active | User_id |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 |      1 |       3 |
|  2 |      1 |       3 |
|  3 |      1 |       3 |
|  4 |      0 |       3 |
|  5 |      0 |       3 |
|  6 |      1 |       1 |
|  7 |      1 |       1 |
|  8 |      1 |       1 |
|  9 |      0 |       1 |
| 10 |      0 |       1 |
+----+--------+---------+
10 rows in set

SELECT * FROM user;
+----+
| Id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
+----+
5 rows in set
```

What I am trying to do is run a query that returns a specific user with only the active tasks in its 'Tasks' collection

```
var query = QueryOver.Of<User>()
    .Where(u => u.Id == 3)
    .JoinQueryOver<Task>(x => x.Tasks)
    .Where(t => t.Active == true);

var results = dataProvider.ExcecuteQuery<User>(query);
```

When I execture this query I expect to get back a single user object with 3 Task objects in its Tasks collection, instead what I get is 3 copies of the same task object (task.Id = 3) all of which have all 5 Tasks in their respective collections.

Is what I am trying to do actually possible or should I just be querying on the Task entity instead?

I hope this is not the case as it would be nice to be able to just see a users active tasks without having to messing around with manual filtering.

Comment: this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790153/nhibernate-filtering-out-results-based-on-child-property looks superficially similar but I cant seem to see the an answer to my question I can understand there

Answer (score 0):

First, I think I would break it up into two queries. In making a master-detail it might make more sense to get the user entities, then get the tasks for the users...

I'm not really good using `QueryOver.Of<T>()`, but here's one way to do it using `session.QueryOver<T>()`:

```
        var users = session.QueryOver<User>()
            .Where(u => u.Id == 3)
            .Fetch(o => o.Tasks)
            .Lazy()
            .SingleOrDefault();

        users.Tasks.TakeWhile(o => o.Active);
```

I think you can use filters too, but it didn't sound like what you wanted to do. I don't think `QueryOver.Of<T>()` does what you want, because the disconnected query would need a filter to correctly pull back the child elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `.TransformUsing( Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)` before `List()` method to get only 1 user object. 
After that what you are seeing is issuing another query to the database to get the list of tasks of that user (without filtering the active ones) and this is the meaning of lazy loading. 
Add `.ShowSql().FormatSql()` in your db config section to see what's happening.

Also you can add this property to your `Task` class

```
public virtual User User { set; get; }
```

To have queries like this: (what you want in the first place)

```
 var list = session.QueryOver<Task>()                                                        
                            .Fetch(t=>t.User).Eager
                            .Where(t => t.Active && t.User.Id==3)
                            .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
                            .List();
```

Comment: Adding the User entity to the Tasks entity is a pretty good idea.